# accessing Java web service from peer in Windows XP Pro Workgroup

Tags: web-services, windows-xp

To set the context of this problem, I will say that I am person trying to learn web services working ( mostly )independently at home on XP workgroup. The situation is that I am working through example in book that set up Java web service that should be accessable to clients from many platforms ( perl, ruby, etc. ). The problem is that although I can create and access service from any one given unit in workgroup, I cannot create on any unit and access from any other unit in workgroup. When trying to access wsdl, IE returns error saying cannot display web page .
 So i tried to configure Windows firewall to allow access via port indicated in web service. Did not make any difference. Also tried various settings in IIS regarding behavior of XP Default website. These settings included allowing wider range of MIME types including application/soap. Still no difference.
 If Anyone out there could just give me an idea of what else could be the problem, then please do so and i will investigate it further. Thanks in advance. PL 
 P.S. After doing some research, I am thinking that my problem of not being to see WSDL from remote machine is related to limitations of IIS 5.1. Does anyone have any thoughts about this ? I even tried publishing WSDL to  port 8080 ( earlier I was using port 9876 as suggested in book example. When even this failed and being able to view 8080 for ASP.Net and Java webapps, I ran across a statement in a book saying that IIS 5.1 does not allow service on local machine to use HTTP port 80 to communicate. So If this sounds familiar to anyone or anyone has solution, please reply, Thanks for reading this rambling message this far. PL

Comment: Are you sure that the web service is up and running? What server are you using for deploying the webservice and what port is the server running?

Comment: Yes Teja, I can see WSDL and Run client on local machine . Results of Client are as expected

Comment: Teja, I am deploying using IIS 5.1 and on port 9876 ( as suggested by example in book ) . Thanks. PL

Answer (score 0):

Hello to any one who might have this similar problem in XP workgroup and need a solution. I managed to connect across workgroup from peer to use service as client by setting up client in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express . Key is to add web reference that will import wsdl from service host . 
Also worth noting is that I changed address of service published to provide server name of host as known by workgroup rather than using localhost designation.
 Still need to find way to connect using other clients such as java, perl and ruby. Maybe can develop client in Eclipse that will have feature comparable to web reference in Visual Web Developer.
              Paul Lusk